# Highcharts problem of dynamic data processing

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the API highcharts to display the number of visitors to my site by country. I receive the data via mysql and I have this table in php:

```
<?php $data = Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => DE [y] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => FR [y] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => US [y] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => XX [y] => 1 ) ); ?>
```

Then at the bottom of my php file, I put my js:

```js
var g_donnes = '<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>';
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: g_donnes
  }]
});
```

So when I make a console.log (g_donnes), I have this table `[{"name":"DE","y":1},{"name":"FR","y":3},{"name":"US","y":1},{"name":"XX","y":1}]`, but cons g_donnes is not treated by the code at the level of data: g_donnes

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need quotes:

```
var g_donnes = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

With quotes your `g_donnes` is **string**, and not an **array** which is required by your code.